# Allowing "plugin" programmers to subscribe to messages

Tags: java, exception-handling

I am having difficulty deciding how to implement an exception handling strategy.

I am using an observer pattern to allow "plugin" programmers to subscribe to `Message`s. These subscribers generally log a unique error (and do some other stuff) under an exceptional circumstance during handling the message. The code snippet below is an example of what a common implementation (and its interface) looks like:

```
// API interface
interface IMessageListener {
   void onMessage(Message m);
}

class StuffMessageListener implements IMessageListener {
    ...

    @Override void onMessage(Message m) {

        try {
            Stuff s = stuffDAO.getStuff(..); // throws SQLException

            ...

            m.reply(true);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // if an exception happens, log it, and reply to the message
            log.error(A_UNIQUE_ERROR_CODE, e);
            m.reply(false);
        }
    }
}
```

What irks me is that the catch block has become very redundant code, copied throughout 95% of the ~50 existing listeners. Can we come up with something better?

A good solution should:

- be easy to use/understand for an amateur programmer
- keep the programmer aware of the existence/potential of exceptions
- minimize the chance of a programmer accidentally "swallowing" an exception
- reduce the amount of "boilerplate" code

There is a subtle requirement needed for the solution. The `UNIQUE_ERROR_CODE` should be unique across all **declarations** of the listeners. That way, I could gain statistics based upon where the error was caught across all listeners.

If the `UNIQUE_ERROR_CODE` is buried underneath an abstract class, or is used outside `onMessage(..)`, I will lose the needed "uniqueness."

Comment: What does `m.reply(boolean)` do?

Comment: It signals to the sender of the message that the handling was (un)successful.

Comment: Why not make it assume by default that it was unsuccessful?

Comment: Thx for the suggestion @NickODell. I could use that strategy and add a `suppressReply()` method, but I'm not sure how much I like that.. The reason for this new method is because in some cases, the message should not be replied to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Allow throwing exceptions

Do you really think your user is capable of handling all the exceptions?

```
interface IMessageListener {
   void onMessage(Message m) throws Exception;
}
```

Of course if some plugin wants to handle the exception, nothing prevents he/she of using `try/catch`. But no one is forced to do so and if, according to your knowledge, the `catch` block is almost always the same, put it outside in the code calling `onMessage()`.

## Give your user a simplified adapter

```
abstract class ThrowingMessageListenerAdapter implements IMessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message m) {
        try {
            doOnMessage(m);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // if an exception happens, log it, and reply to the message
            log.error(A_UNIQUE_ERROR_CODE, e);
            m.reply(false);
        }
    }

    protected abstract void doOnMessage(Message m) throws Exception;

}
```

Comment: I really like this answer. However, there is a fixed requirement that the user must not throw a exception in the `onMessage()` (like JMS). Please check my update to know why the adapter solution will not preserve unique error codes.

Answer (score 6):

This looks like a good place to use an abstract class instead of an interface:

```
abstract class MessageListener{
    void onMessage(Message m){
        try{ onMessageLogic(m); }
        catch(Exception e){ ... }
    }
    abstract void onMessageLogic(Message m) throws Exception;
}

class StuffMessageListener extends MessageListener{
    onMessageLogic(Message m) throws Exception{  
        /* possibly exception-raising code here */  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

best thing would be to

implement `getStuff` method with Message m as a parameter to it.
This way you can catch the exception inside your method which set

```
m.reply(true) or m.reply(false)
```

inside your code
itself making it easier for others to use it.

Comment: Side effects should be avoided, not encouraged.